# Build dynamically tables at RTF

Tags: .net, rtf

I would like build dynamically tables (unknown compile-time number of tables, rows, merging cell, etc)

Is there any good way(may be some nice dll?) for working with rtf besides low - level tag writing following rtf format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating tables isn't that hard with RTF, knowing the Control Words is the toughest part. I've worked with them in C# WPF. The trick with RTF Tables is that each row is independent of the rest of the table. So, Row 1 doesn't know that Row 2 is a part of the same table, and vis a vis.

The following code will create a table for the specified number of rows / columns. If you want to programmatically merge cells, you would have to keep track of the cells to merge and just run one less Row Cell loop.

```
private String GetTableRTF(int numRows, int numColumns)
    {
        StringBuilder rtfTableString = new StringBuilder();

        // For each row, construct the rtf version of a row            
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            // Start the row, autofits it to the page and gives it a black border by default
            rtfTableString.Append(@"{\trowd\trautofit1");
            rtfTableString.Append(@"\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf11"); // Top border
            rtfTableString.Append(@"\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf11"); // Left border
            rtfTableString.Append(@"\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf11"); // Bottom border
            rtfTableString.Append(@"\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf11"); // Right border
            rtfTableString.Append(@"\trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf11"); // Cell Horizontal border
            rtfTableString.Append(@"\trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf11"); // Cell Vertical border

            for (int z = 0; z < numColumns; z++)
            {
                // Create the cells for the table
                rtfTableString.Append(@"{\intbl \cell}");
            }
            //finish the row
            rtfTableString.Append(@"\row}");
        }

        return rtfTableString.ToString();
    }
```

This would give you a basic table that will autofit to the window and have a basic black border. Any further design tweaks would be up to you.